# Weird results with Intervals

Tags: intervals

Sorry for presumably another dumb question... But here we go:

```
Reduce[Sin[Cos[x]] == 0 && 0 <= x <= Pi/2, x]

(* x == Pi/2 *)
```

Yep. Nice.

So now, a seemingly equivalent statement:

```
Reduce[Sin[Cos[x]] == 0 && IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, Pi/2}], x], x]

(* False *)
```

Fun...

Where's my mistake?

PS.

```
Reduce[Equivalent[0 <= x <= Pi/2, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, Pi/2}], x]], x]

(* x < 0 || x > Pi/2 *)
```

Funny as well.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say how to fix it, but the explanation is simple:

```
 IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, Pi/2}], x]
```

for the symbolic `x` immediately returns `False`, so your statements are:

```
 Reduce[ whatever && False , x ] (* False *)
```

and

```
 Reduce[Equivalent[0 <= x <= Pi/2, False], x]
```

which is the same as :

```
 Reduce[! (0 <= x <= Pi/2), x]
```

hence

> x < 0 || x > Pi/2

Comment: It's a shame, that you're not sure how to fix this, because annoying things like that really often cause frustration and I would like to read up on the subject. But I do have an idea here. Is it the case that `0<=x<=Pi/2` is neither `True` nor `False` and remains unevaluated, while `IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, Pi/2}], x]]` is roughly equivalent to `TrueQ[0<=x<=Pi/2]` and necessarily returns `False`?

Comment: When evaluating statements such as `IntervalMemberQ[{0, Pi/2}],x]` without prior assignment of $x$ *Mathematica* necessarily returns `False` because $x$ might in fact be assigned a value for which the Boolean statement is `False`.  This structure (properly) appears numerous places throughout *Mathematica*, such as assuming a function's value is `Real` when in fact it might be more restrictive and an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the behavior you describe was given in @george's answer. Starting in M10, the proper way to use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) with [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) objects is to make use of the new in M10 [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) functionality. So:

```
Reduce[Sin[Cos[x]] == 0 && {x} ∈ Interval[{0, π/2}], x]
```

> x == π/2